# Exactly storing large integers

Tags: r, algorithm, precision, floating-point-precision

In R software

```
a <- 123456789123456789123456789
sprintf("%27f",a)
#[1] "123456789123456791337762816.000000"
```

I got the wrong answer. I want exact `a` value.

Why is the system showing the wrong value of `a`?

Comment: Also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339636/long-numbers-as-a-character-string)

Comment: As explained in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419024/is-there-a-way-to-display-frank-nelson-coles-factors-of-267-%e2%88%92-1-correctly-with#comment68089039_40419024) (under a duplicate question), do not forget to pass a character when using  `gmp::as.bigz()`.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you're not getting your exact value of `a` is that R is storing it as a double instead of as an integer. Because `a` is very large, there is some rounding that takes place when you assign `a`.

Normally to store things as integers you would use `L` at the end of the numbers; something like:

```
a <- 12L
class(a)
# [1] "integer"
```

However your number is too large for a standard integer in R, and you're forced to use the double representation:

```
a <- 123456789123456789123456789L
# Warning message:
# non-integer value 123456789123456789123456789L qualified with L; using numeric value 
class(a)
# [1] "numeric"
```

You will need multiple precision to exactly store an integer this large. One option would be the `gmp` package:

```
library(gmp)
a<-as.bigz("123456789123456789123456789")
a
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 123456789123456789123456789
```

Other options for multi-precision arithmetic are available under the "Multi-Precision Arithmetic and Symbolic Mathematics" subheading of the [numerical mathematics CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NumericalMathematics.html).

Comment: a<-as.bigz("2*3*7*43*1807*3263443")                                                          If i type like this,    Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] NA  it shows like this, so what i do?

Comment: @aarthi you should store each as a bigz and then multiply; something like `prod(as.bigz(c(2, 3, 7, 43, 1807, 3263443)))`

Comment: factorize( 113423713055421844361000443) and factorize(113423713055421845118910464) have the same answer what i do?