# Unique combination per group

Tags: r, unique, distinct

I have a DT with three columns, and the two first ones have various values grouped by Group.

```
ID            ID_2                    Group
23201600101793 2016052016051062331    A
23201600101793 2016062016061017838    A
23201600101794 2016052016051062331    A
23201600101794 2016052016051062402    A
23201600103090 2016052016051062325    A
23201600103090 2016052016051062408    A
23201600803366 2016052016051062325    A
23201600803366 2016052016051062408    A
```

I need to find a unique combination of both columns, withtout repeated values in any column. My desire output is for Group A is

```
ID            ID_2                    Group
23201600101793 2016052016051062331    A
23201600101794 2016052016051062402    A
23201600103090 2016052016051062325    A
23201600803366 2016052016051062408    A
```

Lines 3 and 7 were removed because they have repeated values in column ID_2 in lines 1 and 5, respectively. Lines 2, 4, 6 and 8 were removed because they repeat values from column ID in lines 1, 3, 5, 7.

There isn't a pattern by group, they can have many rows with the same ID or ID_2.

For example, from group B I just need 2 rows, since ID has two unique values. The selected rows can be the first ones (I mean, all the ID_2 rows but the first would be discarted since the first row has two unique values)

```
ID            ID_2                 Group
23201600009182 2016042016041000942 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000943 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000946 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000949 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000950 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000951 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000953 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000954 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000956 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000957 B
23201600009182 2016042016041000958 B
23201600669635 2016052016051003624 B
23201600669635 2016052016051003626 B
23201600669635 2016052016051003628 B
23201600669753 2016012016011000791 B
23201600669753 2016012016011000797 B
```

Desired output of Group B

```
23201600009182 2016042016041000942 B   
23201600669635 2016052016051003624 B
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: In your `DT` you have 5 unique values of `ID_2` and 4 in `ID`, is that correct? Are you aware of working with [large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368555/exactly-storing-large-integers) in R?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want `Group` & `ID` to be unique.

You can use `distinict` in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

#sample data
set.seed(123)
sample_data <- tibble(ID = sample(1:4,size = 10,replace = T),
                      ID2 = sample(1:4,size = 10,replace = T),
                      group = sample(c("A","B"),size = 10,replace = T))
```

Sample data:

```
> sample_data
# A tibble: 10 x 3
ID   ID2 group
<int> <int> <chr>
    1     2     4 B    
2     4     2 B    
3     2     3 B    
4     4     3 B    
5     4     1 B    
6     1     4 B    
7     3     1 B    
8     4     1 B    
9     3     2 A    
10     2     4 A   

#sample result
distinct(sample_data,ID,group,.keep_all=T)
```

sample result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
ID   ID2 group
<int> <int> <chr>
    1     2     4 B    
2     4     2 B    
3     1     4 B    
4     3     1 B    
5     3     2 A    
6     2     4 A
```

Comment: But this is different from the expected output.

Comment: The outcome of this function with the DT I posted, it won't work. It gets the unique values of ID, but ID_2 are repeated.