# Strong behavior with large numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, unique, largenumber

I had an issue while trying to asnwer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820902/unique-combination-per-group).

I got this vector with large numbers:

```
large1 <- c(2016052016051062331, 2016062016061017838,
            2016052016051062331, 2016052016051062402,
            2016052016051062325, 2016052016051062408,
            2016052016051062325, 2016052016051062408)
```

As we can see there're 5 unique numbers in this `numeric` vector. However when I do an `unique` I got only 3 values. In addition, it returns different numbers.

```
unique(large1)
#[1] 2.016052e+18 2.016062e+18 2.016052e+18
```

I've tried to change the digits using `options(digits = 20)` but got same result:

```
options(digits = 20)
unique(large1)
#[1] 2016052016051062272 2016062016061017856 2016052016051062528
```

Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368555/exactly-storing-large-integers

Comment: I saw those posts and I don't think this is a duplicate because I want unique values from a vector of large numbers.

Comment: this is due to a floating point error, common in almoast all programming languages.... a possible workaround is to store the numbers as characters, an other possibility is rounding your numbers to a couple of digits.

Comment: Well the question itself is not a duplicate, although I accepted as duplicated

Comment: Possibly the bit64 package might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you @Roland!